# .vbs facebook program not entering username and password

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a program that asks the user their username and password for facebook in two seperate input boxes and then opens internet explorer and then goes to facebook.com and enters the username and password and logs in.  Well, when I run the code you see down in the bottom it dosen't work because for some reason internet explorer is not selected when it opens so I have to click on it, and it never enters the username or password!

CODE:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ie, x

Set ie = createobject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set x = createobject("wscript.shell")

Sub Load
Do while ie.Busy
wscript.sleep 200
Loop
End Sub

ie.Navigate "https://www.facebook.com/"

ie.Toolbar=0
ie.StatusBar=0
ie.Resizable=1
ie.Visible=1

Call Load
x.sendkeys "cow"
x.sendkeys "{tab}"
x.sendkeys "pass"
```

Comment: [AppActivate](http://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html) might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ie, x

Set ie = createobject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set x = createobject("wscript.shell")

ie.Visible=1
ie.Toolbar=0
ie.StatusBar=0
ie.Resizable=1

Sub Load
Do while ie.Busy
wscript.sleep 100
Loop
End Sub

x.AppActivate "Microsoft Internet Explorer"

ie.Navigate "https://www.facebook.com/"

Call Load


x.sendkeys "cow"
x.sendkeys "{tab}"
x.sendkeys "pass"
```

The main take-aways are -

1. Make the window visible before navigating to facebook. (Or atleast before AppActivate)
2. Use AppActivate to select the Window before passing id/password.